# How to use "to take a picture of/with"?

Tags: phrase-usage

There are three people named A, B and C.

1. If A wants himself and B to be in a picture taken by C, how can A ask C?
2. If A and B want A, B and C to be in a picture, how can they ask C?
3. If A want B and C to be in a picture taken by himself (by A), what can A say to them?
   I think I know the answers but I need confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: Well, why don't you provide the answers if you know them. It will be better that way for you to understand what you thought wrong or did wrong.

Comment: If using "have" in scenario 2, can I say "C, could we have a picture?"?

Comment: These are not question about English.

Answer (score 0):

Take a picture of A - A will be in the picture and will be the main focus of the picture . A could be a group of people.

Take a picture with A - A will be in the picture alongside some other object or person. "Will you take a picture with me?" means the speaker and the listener will be in the picture together.

So for your scenarios:

1. "Can ('will', 'would' or 'could' also work here) you take a picture of us?" 'Us' (person A and B) is in the picture and is the main focus.
2. "Can(/will/would/could) you take a picture with us?" 'Us' (person A and B) will be in the picture alongside 'you' (person C)
3. "Can('could' also works here but 'will' and 'would' do not) I take a picture of you?" 'you' (Plural 'you' meaning person B and C) will be the main focus of the picture

Comment: Ok, thanks. In scenario 2, your question suggests that C is the one who takes a picture? Would it be wrong to say "can we take a picture with you?"?

Comment: When saying "Can you take a picture with us?" it does seem like you are asking them to take the picture but usually it wouldn't mean this and you would expect whoever has the camera to take the picture. "Can we take a picture with you?" is a good option as well. It is natural and may be more clear.

Comment: (To C) Would you [like to] be in the picture with us?

Comment: Can I use "may"  in scenario 3?

Comment: Yes. 'may' would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

To "take a picture of X" means that X is visible in the picture.

We usually don't say "take a picture with X". That could mean that X and something X are in the picture. Or it could mean that X and someone else are behind the camera taking the pictures. You can say "take a picture of X with Y", meaning X and Y are both in the picture.

So in your examples:

1. If A wants himself and B to be in a picture taken by C, how can A ask C?

"C, would you take a picture of B and me?"

2. If A and B want A, B and C to be in a picture, how can they ask C?

"C, will you be in a picture with B and me?" or "Will you let D take a picture of you, B, and me?"

3. If A want B and C to be in a picture taken by himself (by A), what can A say to them?

"B and C, can I take a picture of the two of you?"